# Netbeans on Linux Mint only starts when run with sudo

Tags: permissions, linux-mint

I've installed Netbeans directly from the oracle site (the 7.4 Release but also the 8.0 Release Candidate). I really want to install the least possible version, so the one in the apt repos's doesn't help me.

I install Netbeans with my user account directly into my home directory, the installation is only usable for my user. I do this because it should be possible to code and deploy applications to tomcat or glassfish without starting netbeans as root. So my glassfish development server is also installed with my local user account. This is also an aspect why I don't like getting netbeans over apt, because it's hard to use this glassfish as a development server then (where is the webapp directory? where is the the config? Where are the logfiles? is it possible to quickly change the config then? I dont want my development server to start on system startup, it should only run when I am developing, and so on).

The problem now is, that netbeans is installed and also the starters appear on my desktop, but when I double click them, the netbeans splash screen appears and then nothing happens.

When I `sudo netbeans`, it works, but thats actually not a solution for me. It just points out, that this has something to do with permissions.

So which permissions do I have to set, that I am able to run netbeans (and tomcat, and glassfish) with my everyday user account?

Comment: if `sudo netbeans` works, does `netbeans` works too?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. As expected it behaves the same way as just clicking on the Netbeans Icon on the Desktop.

Comment: What port does it listen on when started as root? If it's configured to listen to a port less than 1024 then only root can do that.

Comment: First, you should check which command is executed by the starter icon, and then issue the very same command manually on the console. It might be a privilges issue, or something regarding the JRE / JDK.

Comment: @AmosShapira Glassfish is configured for port 8080...but first of all netbeans needs to get startet. glassfish then will be started by netbeans, when I run/deploy a project. I even am not able to get netbeans running without root.

Comment: @tohuwawohu The command behind the icon is `/bin/sh "/home/<user>/dev/netbeans-8.0rc1/bin/netbeans"` . If I put this into commandline again the splashscreen shows up, then goes away and nothing more happens. The shell returns with no error. I'll try to pipe Stderr out...one moment

Comment: You could try to recursively change the ownership of the Netbeans-related files: `sudo chown -R <youruser>:users /home/<youruser>/dev/netbeans-8.0rc1`

Comment: mhm...chown didn't help. And Stderr also isn't putting out anything. Is there a system wide log of mint or cinnamon where I might gather some information (like /var/log/syslog)?